# UIImagePickerController slow on opening for the first time, except for when you double tap

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm getting this really weird behaviour on iOS 9 with swift where I have a `tableViewCell` that opens an `imagePicker` when tapped on to take a picture of something, when you tap the cell for the first time it takes like 10 seconds to open the picker, but when you tap it twice it immediately opens...

The initialisation code for the picker is as follows

```
let certificateImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
certificateImagePicker.delegate = self
certificateImagePicker.allowsEditing = false
certificateImagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
certificateImagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .CurrentContext
```

The code for presenting the picker is `presentViewController(certificateImagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)`

I do not now if it related but after opening the picker it show this error message

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot.
>       Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or 
>       snapshot after screen updates.

Comment: Are you presenting the picker from a background thread? Also, why are setting the presentation style to `.CurrentContext`?

Answer (score 9):

I experienced a similar delay in presenting a `UIImagePickerController` on the first try. What helped a lot in my case was initialising it when also initializing the parent `UIViewController`, like so:

```swift
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
  let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

  func presentImagePicker() {
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is only for debug builds, when you run an app connected to Xcode.

Comment: ^This. You can still use a debug scheme just make sure you aren't connected to Xcode.

Comment: This issue is when we run iphone connected with xcode. I kill the app from debug mode and when i run, it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
private var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
...
@objc func addPhoto() {
 imagePickerController.delegate = self
 imagePickerController.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
        
  present(imagePickerController, animated: true)
}
...
```

When I have this implementation it was waiting when the first present was attempted then after changed my variable to `lazy variable`, then it worked like charm.

```
private lazy var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above tricks helped me, instead, I came up with a hacky way to solve this:

Just present and dissmiss the image picker during ViewDidLoad, that will force the controller to load itself:

```
lazy var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    present(imagePicker, animated: false)
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: false)
    // rest of your code
}
```

Just be aware that this can slightly impact the overal load time, but it is definitely better than keeping the user waiting.