# Presenting a UIImagePickerController is quite slow

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

My phone has about 2000 photos. When I present a `UIImagePickerController`, it takes ~3-4 seconds. How can I optimize this operation?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this Issue in your actual device ?

Comment: what type of iPhone?

Comment: you should include more details about your situation, what are you trying to achieve, a snippet of your code, anything that can help pinpoint what might be the problem, more often than not, the assumption of the problem is not the real problem, The `UIImagePickerController ` displays a list of assets that have cached thumbnails, such a list should work smoothly regardless of the amount of photos on the device, most likely, there is a problem in your code that denies the `UIImagePickerController ` to pop up when you click on the import button, sharing you code/implementation will probably help

Comment: Yes, my iphone 6.

Comment: Sadly, this is just a side effect of using a `UIImagePickerController`. You can handle this issue by implementing a custom image picker which uses a more efficient image loading or simply displaying an activity indicator to let the user know that it's loading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController slow on opening for the first time, except for when you double tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819118/uiimagepickercontroller-slow-on-opening-for-the-first-time-except-for-when-you)

Comment: In fact, not only in the first time.

Answer (score -1):

Write the code of `UIImagePickerController` inside the `DispatchQueue`.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //UIImagePickerController code goes here
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how and why this makes anything faster?